# Swift 3 - JSON Parsing

Tags: json, parsing, swift3, error-handling

I am new to Swift and learning the basics.

What I want to ask is, is it a good practice to parse JSON in terms of error handling as below?

```
if  let email = data["Email"] as? String,
                let name = data["Name"] as? String,
                let surname = data["Surname"] as? String,
                let identityNumber = data["IdentityNumber"] as? String ?? nil,
                let regAddress = data["RegistrationAddress"] as? String,
                let regZipCode = data["RegistrationZipCode"] as? String,
                let phoneNumber = data["PhoneNumber"] as? String,
                let city = data["City"] as? String {

                let user = User(name: name, surname: surname, idNumber: identityNumber, regAddress: regAddress, regZipCode: regZipCode, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, city: city)
            }
```

Any help or answer is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to create the user only if **all** fields are valid then yes, it's a good practice. By the way the nil coalescing operator `?? nil` is meaningless. Either the value is not `nil` then the evaluation will be continued otherwise the rest of the expression will be skipped anyway. And if you could cast `data` to `[String:String]` (all values are `String`) then you can get rid of all `as? String` down casts.

Comment: @vadian thanks for help dude, its appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it will not have any problem, but if the values or result may get nil. so at that time the app will get crash.